# testing hbase with jvmti agent

Tags: java, maven, hbase, jvmti

I want to test hbase using its test cases. I downloaded the project from this [link](http://apache.bilkent.edu.tr/hbase/stable/) and followed the instruction to test the project, which is simply running the command line

```
mvn test
```

There is no problem up to here. What I want to do is to run test cases with `jvmti agent`. The agent works perfectly fine, I tried it on several java files. Normally, I call my agent to test a java file using

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/agent/agent.so javaProgram
```

In this case, the project use maven and I am not good at pom files. I tried to use

```
alias java="java -agentpath:/path/to/agent/agent.so "
```

However it did not wok. How can I test hbase with my agent?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass JVM arguments to maven by using the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable:

`export MAVEN_OPTS=-agentpath:/path/to/agent.so`

A more generic solution is to use `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable.

On linux: `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentpath:/path/to/agent.so` and then run `mvn`

Comment: I found several methods to solve this problem, your solutions work as well. However, the agent only gathers information about execution of maven, not the running test cases. Maven calls java and creates an jvm for itself. Then, it runs everything on it or creates another jvm to run test cases. So, the agent is not called for the execution of test cases. I could not get the main idea.

Comment: AFAIK JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS will propagate to the "internal" test jvms as well

Comment: same method right? export AFAIK JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentpath:/path/to/agent.so

Comment: I thought AFAIK is like a command :) Anyway, I tried JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS on it and on several other projects as well but it is again no use. It just collects the execution information of maven.